# Collect set of collect set in hive/ SQL

Tags: sql, group-by, hive

I have data in the following format:

```
Tin Month Code
A   Jan   P53
A   Jan   P54
A   Jan   P53
A   Feb   P54
A   Feb   P55
B   Jan   P55
B   Jan   P51
B   Feb   P51
B   Feb   P51
```

Now I want to group this data in two steps.
Firstly by Tin and Month:

```
TIN  Month Code_set
A    Jan    ['P53','P54']
A    Feb    ['P54','P55']
B    Jan    ['P55','P51']
B    Feb    ['P51']
```

I can easily do this using `collect_set`.
Further I want to group this data at Tin level using this grouped data in the following way:

```
Tin Code_set
A   ['P53','P54','P55']
B   ['P55','P51']
```

Now, I can easily achieve this using `collect_Set` on the initial raw data, though I wanted to do this on the grouped data.
Is there any way this is possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would unnest  using `explode()` and recollecct:

```
select g.tin, collect_set(code)
from grouped g lateral view
     explode(g.codes) explodeval as code
group by g.tin;
```

Comment: Hi Godon, this was useful..please make just one edit for the future users, `explode(g.codes) explodeVal as code` .